# CSplitterWnd flip between horizontal and vertical splitter?

Tags: mfc, csplitterwnd

Suppose I have a splitter with 2 rows.

> --------
> |        |
> --------
> |        |
> --------

How do I make it to this

> ---------
> |    |    |
> |    |    |
> |    |    |
> ---------

switch from horizontal split to vertical split

without having to re-create the whole splitter?

Code is:

```
if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create splitter window\n");
    return FALSE;
}
if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd), CSize(200, 100), NULL))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create CView1\n");
    return FALSE;
}
if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 2, RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd), CSize(500, 100), NULL))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create CView2\n");
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: wow. nobody managed to answer :| ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CreateStatic`, just use `Create` on the splitter. Then you have a so called dynamic splitter, see more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/969ca366%28VS.80%29.aspx).

When converting the splitter from horz to vert, you have to remove the views from the splitter and attach them again afterwards. You have to do this in your document-class. I can post a method to do this if needed.

Ok, here is a method to switch views in a pane:

```
CView* CGMBefundDoc::SwitchToView(CView* pNewView,int row,int col)
{
CMainFrame* pMainWnd = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
CSplitterWnd* pSplitter = &pMainWnd->m_wndSplitter;

CView* pOldActiveView = reinterpret_cast<CView*>(pSplitter->GetPane(row,col));
ASSERT(pOldActiveView != pNewView);

// set flag so that document will not be deleted when view is destroyed
m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;    
// Dettach existing view
RemoveView(pOldActiveView);
// set flag back to default 
m_bAutoDelete = TRUE;

// Set the child window ID of the active view to the ID of the corresponding
// pane. Set the child ID of the previously active view to some other ID.
::SetWindowLong(pOldActiveView->m_hWnd, GWL_ID, 0);
::SetWindowLong(pNewView->m_hWnd,GWL_ID,pSplitter->IdFromRowCol(row,col));

// Show the newly active view and hide the inactive view.
pNewView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
pOldActiveView->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

// Attach new view
AddView(pNewView);

// Set active 
pSplitter->GetParentFrame()->SetActiveView(pNewView);
pSplitter->RecalcLayout(); 

return pOldActiveView;
}
```

I hope you get the idea, otherwise just ask.

Answer (score 0):

-----------|----------|
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |----------|
|            |            |
|            |            | 
-----------|----------|

2 column splitter with right side having 2 rows, one Up and one Down and another one with left side to the Up and Down ?